# Sharepoint library item properties not saving

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

For some reason, as of recent; when I attempt to add a document to a library in sharepoint I get a pop up to add in specific properties but when I save the item- none of the properties save.

I then have to go back and edit the item again.

Anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The properties is saved in the document library, and not on the document itself. If you open the document from the document library you will see the SharePoint Document library in the Document Information Panel (DIP).

Access the DIP through File > Properties > Advanced Properties.